# Extending a minimum production time required problem

Tags: python, minimum

I have made the following program to find the minimum production time required to produce m products:

```
def minTime(arr, n, m): 

    # Intialise time, items equal to 0. 
    t = 0

    while (1): 

        items = 0

        # Calculating items at each second 
        for i in range(n): 
            items += (t // arr[i]) 

        # If items equal to m return time. 
        if (items >= m): 
            return t 

        t += 1 # Increment time
```

So `arr` is an array containing the number of product machine `i` produces (`arr[i]`) per time unit, `n` is the length of `arr` and `m` is the number of products needed. Now i'm trying to extent this case to a production scheme like:

- Machine 1 produces 2 products in 2 days
- Machine 2 produces 4 products in 5 days
- etc

So a machine that produces 2 products in 2 days will have, zero after 1 day and 2 at the end of day 2!!!

I figured the input would be a matrix instead of an array with the first column giving the number of products that can be produced and the second the corresponding number of days, I might need binary-search to find the days that belong to a certain number of products produced.

Does anyone have any hints/example code for me? I'm struggling to find a solution.